# how to write a backtracking concatenated parser in haskell

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to get a parser created from concatenated parsers to backtrack in parsec.

here's the code:

```
ab = (try $ char 'a') <|> (try $ char 'b')
cd = (try $ char 'b') <|> (try $ char 'c')
abcd = (try $ many1 ab) >> (try cd)
```

here, when I run

```
parse abcd "parser"
```

with the input "aaaaaaaaaaaaaac", it works,
but it errors on "aaaaaaaaaaaaab", which should be acceptable.

Any insights as to what I can do to get this to work

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this a typo in the cd?  a b instead of a d?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you're trying to write the regular expression `(a|b)+(b|c)` in Haskell? This is how you would do it:

```haskell
import Text.Parsec.String
import Text.Parsec

ab :: Parser Char
ab = char 'a' <|> char 'b'

bc :: Parser Char
bc = char 'b' <|> char 'c'

abc :: Parser String
abc = do
    a <- ab
    b <- bc
    return [a,b]

abbc :: Parser String
abbc = try abc <|> do
    c <- ab
    s <- abbc
    return (c:s)

parser :: String -> Either ParseError String
parser = parse abbc "(a|b)+(b|c)"
```

Now load up `ghci` and run the code as follows:

```bash
aaditmshah@home:~$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :load Test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> parser "aaaaaaaaaaaaaac"
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.10.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.1.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package text-0.11.3.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package parsec-3.1.5 ... linking ... done.
Right "aaaaaaaaaaaaaac"
*Main> parser "aaaaaaaaaaaaaab"
Right "aaaaaaaaaaaaaab"
*Main> 
Leaving GHCi.
```

How does this work? Let's understand it parser by parser:

```haskell
ab :: Parser Char
ab = char 'a' <|> char 'b'

bc :: Parser Char
bc = char 'b' <|> char 'c'
```

These two parsers are simple. They correspond to the regular expressions `(a|b)` and `(b|c)` respectively.

```haskell
abc :: Parser String
abc = do
    a <- ab
    b <- bc
    return [a,b]
```

This is also relatively simple. It corresponds to the regular expression `(a|b)(b|c)`.

```haskell
abbc :: Parser String
abbc = try abc <|> do
    c <- ab
    s <- abbc
    return (c:s)
```

This is where things get complicated. This parser does the following:

1. It tries to match the input with the regular expression `(a|b)(b|c)`.
2. If it fails then it doesn't consume any input. Instead it matches the first character of input with `(a|b)` and then goes back to step 1 to match the rest of the input.

Hence it corresponds to the regular expression `(a|b)*(a|b)(b|c)` which is the same as `(a|b)+(b|c)`.

The `try` combinator is important. Without it the parser will try to match the input with `(a|b)(b|c)`. Failing to do so it will throw an error instead of backtracking and trying the alternate condition.

Comment: Btw, `abc = sequence [ab,bc]` and `abbc = try abc <|> ((:) <$> ab <*> abbc)`

Comment: @maxtaldykin That's good, but I feel monadic code is easier to explain than `sequence` or applicative functors.

Comment: yep, of course, this was just a side note for curious reader.

Comment: so if i wanted many ab rather than many1 abc, I would just have abbc = try bc <|> ((:) <$> ab <*> abbc) ?

Answer (score 0):

Aadit's answer will work fine.  Alternatively, if you just want to parse the text and don't need any return value, you can use `manyTill`:

```haskell
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.Parsec.String

ab :: Parser Char
ab = char 'a' <|> char 'b'

bc :: Parser Char
bc = char 'b' <|> char 'c'

abbc :: Parser ()
abbc = ab >> manyTill ab bc >> return ()
```

It works:

```
> parse abbc "" "aaaaaaaaaaaaaac"
Right ()
> parse abbc "" "aaaaaaaaaaaaaab"
Right ()
```

However, if you actually want the parsed text, then `manyTill` is not as convenient since it will only return the values parsed by its first argument, not the second.  (In this example I've discarded those values by calling `return ()`.)